# Android - how to check if in app purchase has already been done?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

How do i check if a in app purchase has been done before?
So that my user doesnt need to repurchase the in app purchase upon uninstalling and reinstalling the app?

I have set my in app item to managable in the android market publish page.

i have read about `RESTORE_TRANSACTION` but I do not know what i need to look for inside this response and also how to test this.

Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to restore the transactions, using the RESTORE_TRANSACTION flag you specified above. You should only do this once, when the application starts for the first time or if the user clears the data.

I would advice to make this process simpler for yourself, you looking into the [AndroidBillingLibrary](https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary/blob/master/DungeonsRedux/src/net/robotmedia/billing/example/Dungeons.java), which allows you to interface with the Android In App Billing in a much simpler manner.

Here is a snippet of how the transactions are restored:

```
private void restoreTransactions() {
    if (!mBillingObserver.isTransactionsRestored()) {
        BillingController.restoreTransactions(this);
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.restoring_transactions, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: So at that point the purchases are stored on the device itself? What if I buy an item on an other device, how does the first device know that? Do I need to restore transactions again?